# how to use custom field names of user table in auth in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have a field of **user_email** in **tbl_users** instead of default **email** field in **user** table. I am facing an error while **registration**, even I have changed the **User** model like `protected $table = 'tbl_users';` but still got the below error.

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydb.users'
>   doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where
>   `email` = test@test.com)

why is it still **users** table?

Comment: You need to change the migration file for the users table in `database/migrations` directory and run `migrate:refresh`

Comment: I have gone through the migration. You mean I have to set migration file before executing "php artisan make:auth"?

Comment: Are you using the default auth scaffolding or did you implement your own / change them?  (Does your backtrace show the User model?)

Comment: I have created migration file according to my required table and now I am stuck here. I didn't do anything by my own just my migration was change.

Comment: I am using the default files of laravel

Comment: did you change guard on config/auth.php or user model?

Comment: @Ben No.. I didn't have idea about that. let me try, what should I change there?

Comment: I have made changes in the model.. let me comment that here for your information

Comment: protected $table = 'tbl_users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    public $timestamps = false;